# Would primitive weaponry be useful when scaled down to microscopic size? ( series )

Tags: weapons, microorganisms, microscopic

*As part of a series of questions that I've been doing about microscopic humanoids ...*

In my world , there are a race of microscopic humanoid organisms ( 0.2 mm - 0.22 mm ) . They live in a variety of biomes , such as leaf litter , stone , and on plants and trees. My questions is -

Would weapons such as axes and spears be useful when scaled down to such sizes , especially against small arthropods such as ants and Pseudoscorpions?

Comment: Note that, square cube law aside, mechanical properties of materials are very different at small scales. Air drag is also higher, so you won't be able to throw things efficiently.

Comment: @Davidmh how can that be so when their is proportionally less air per unit?

Comment: Think about it like this: why can an artillery shell fly further than a bullet, even though their basic shape is pretty much the same? The momentum of the projectile increases faster than the amount of momentum lost to air drag. Drag is a bit complex, but it roughly grows with surface area in an aerodynamic projectile - on the other hand, momentum grows with mass, which grows with volume. It's just another application of the square-cube law :)

Comment: @TheoclesofSaturn fluid dynamics is complicated, but the gist is that smaller fluids become more viscous. Look at dust: small pieces can float on the air for long periods of time, but as soon as they clump up, they fall to the floor and hide whenever you can't clean them away.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, your humans are too small.

A 0.2mm tall human is about 9000 times shorter than a 1.8m human, but its volume, and thus its mass, drops by 9000<sup>3</sup> or 729,000,000,000.  A typical 70kg human becomes just 0.00009mg.  Let's look at your expected opponent.

A [typical black garden ant is about 4mm long](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_garden_ant#Appearance), or 20 times longer than your humans are tall.  A [Brontosaurus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brontosaurus), at 20m long, is only 10 times longer than a human is tall. [Black ants weigh 1.5mg](http://www.antweb.org/cgi-bin/mt/mt-search.cgi?IncludeBlogs=1&tag=ant%20weight&limit=20) or 16,000 times more than your humans.  By comparison an [African Elephant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/African_bush_elephant) only weighs 150 times a normal human.

Here is what that would look like.

[image: Ant versus tiny human]

Here is a human and an elephant for comparison.

[image]

Your humans simply would not have enough mass to affect an ant.  Nor would they have enough height to do anything but poke at its legs.

Trying to scale humans down has myriad problems.  This video on [What Would Happen If You Were Shrunk?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xkvo-DrU2gM#t=3m09s) by VSauce3 scratches the surface.

Comment: An interesting, although sceptical analysis. What about strategy? If nothing else ants can swarm a larger enemy (and in some cases kill), so why can the mini-humans not do the same? A couple hundred mini-humans swarm the ant - climb it's legs, over it's back and start hacking with mini-axes at it's various joint or something. I admit it's not a good strategy - it would send the ant berserk trying to shake / brush the mini-humans off - killing all (or, at the very least, most) of the mini-humans. Perhaps a trap that ties the ant down long enough for the mini-humans to cut at the joints?

Comment: @RichardParnaby-King To put that to scale, do you think a swarm of 4 gram beings with tiny little axes could take you down? 4 grams is a bit less than the weight of a US quarter coin. I've added a picture for scale.

Comment: Again - strategy. Mini-humans dropping onto the back of the ant and taking off the head. Or make giant masks with water in them to drop over the ant's head and drown the sucker. Find some sort of poisonous mushroom, tip the spears in poison and stab the ants in the joints. Gulliver's Travels - tie the giant down and start carving up for dinner for winter! In summary - one on one there is no way a mini-human will win against an ant; many on one (with a fair whack of strategy) and there's a *chance* of success.

Comment: All this is moot, though. Kill off one ant and it's friends will come looking for it. Won't be long till you have 5+ ants in your little village eating up the people.

Comment: @RichardParnaby-King Taking off the head with a teeny-weeny little axe? Look at a coin. Now imagine that coin with a tiny axe trying to chop your neck off. I think you still don't understand the scale. Let's go the other way and scale the ant up. It's now *40 feet tall and weighs 1 million kg*, or about 15 [M1 tanks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M1_Abrams). You'll drop onto the back of a moving, thrashing 40 foot tall monster? And *from where*? Tie it down? Put a mask on it? It weighs 1 million kg!

Comment: So we go with the poison on a stick approach. Would a 40 foot ant feel me land on it's back? Probably not, no (as long as we don't start rubbing up against the hairs). So me and my buddies rappell down from the top of a flower with a spear long enough to penetrate the joint armour, and poke the poison stick between it's joints. Dead ant 30 seconds later (assuming a naturally occurring poison that the mini-humans can access).

Comment: @RichardParnaby-King You're still not getting the scale. Coating a spear in rat poison isn't enough. Let's assume you get poison from [the most venomous spider](http://www.guinnessworldrecords.com/world-records/most-venomous-spider) and let's assume this works on ants the same as primates (it probably won't). A lethal dose is 0.2mg/kg. To kill a scaled up 1,000,000 kg ant you'd need to acquire 200 g of the stuff, like a can of it, and somehow get it into the ant. Are these primitive humans running a spider venom farm?

Comment: @RichardParnaby-King at that scale the "thin" armor at the joint is thicker than the humans leg, for comparison that is like trying to stick a spear through the thickest part of the shell of a galapagos tortoise doubled up. even if by magic there were strong enough all that would happen would be the pole vault into the air.

Answer (score 4):

What humans are good at is throwing rocks. That should be sufficiently primitive.

Here, like in many other cases, the cube-square law causes problems. A stone is 8000 times smaller, thus it has an area that is $6.4*10^7$. Its volume, however, is $5.12*10^{11}$ times smaller. Having the impact concentrated on a small area is how spears work, and the rock's impact is now much less concentrated. But it gets worse, small creatures can not throw a rock as fast as large creatures. All in all, rock throwing is much less dangerous. Sure, they might push the target a little, but nor brake bones or cause wounds.

Same for a spear, but there, the cube-square effect is cancelled but the fact that it is 8000 times sharper. It is however moving much slower, so no weapons based on hitting the enemy is very efficient.

Comment: A spear is equally affected by the square-cube law. You penetrate because you can put force (roughly proportional to its mass) into a very small area (ie, sharp point, quadratic).

Comment: @Davidmh The square-cube law applies, but there exist two other effects there, and they cancel each other. In the end, the square-square cube law is standing alone.

Answer (score 3):

Basically, what Schwerm has stated. No, you cannot use these *weapons* effectively against those threats. At 0.2 mm (max limit), your people would be able to wield a spear hardly more than 0.3 mm. By comparison, even a juvenile ant is around 3mm and has 6 legs AND a pair of powerful denticles. An ant bite can send pain waves even in a grown up 6 feet tall human being. How do your people can fare against such a threat when being 1/30 of its length?

To help you think in perspective, would you be able to fight an ant that is double the size of a T-rex? It doesn't need to bite you at all (which would instantaneously clip you in two). Just a *stomp* by that monster ant would be enough to painfully end your life.

Also keep in mind that arthropods have exoskeletons, so that your *weapons* would hit the harder parts of the body first, which further implies that you will not be able to punch a hole through your arthropod adversaries (in perspective, a 6 foot person would have to punch a hole in 2 feet thick bone before his spear could hit the softer tissue inside).

So all in all, no. The weapons would be as useless against such adversaries as you trying to bring down a T-Rex with a spear.

Comment: Why do you think it would be imposible to bring down a T. Rex with spears? Is there some reason why you'd expect it to be harder than hunting, say, mammoths? Also note that all else equal, human muscles, bones etc. are *much* stronger than an ants - if you scale a human down to ant size, it would be much tougher and stronger than the ant. Well, and it would freeze to death almost instantly, I guess. And while ants do have an exoskeleton, they still have plenty of weak spots an intelligent opponent would target - assuming the skeleton was able to deflect their weapons in the first place.

Comment: One simple reason is that the ants are 10 or more times larger in _length_ alone. Compounded with width and height differences the total (volume) difference would be horribly great. I haven't done the math myself, but I'm quoting Schwerm that the overall (volume) difference would be in thousands, as compared to humans and large mammalian alive today, which does not even approach the scale of 500. If you require 5 people with spears to take down an African Bush Elephant (200 times larger) how many would you require to take down an ant around 2000 times larger than you?

Answer (score 2):

While attacking the traditional way will not work, your humans are small enough that they can crawl in through the joints and other openings on your ant. When inside, they are still large enough that they might survive the immune system for some time. Risky business, but such is life for any creature that small.

Inside, the small spears and knives could do significant damage. Maybe the humans could even accomplish rudimentary control of the ants, like some parasites do in the real world.

Comment: If a fungus can do it, why not the mini-humans? - http://www.dailymail.co.uk/sciencetech/article-2730411/

Answer (score 1):

What weapon? **Intelligence**.

I'm looking at Schwern's illustration when contemplating it, BTW. Diagrams like this ought to be part of the OP's posts.  Now that he understands the scale that should be presented goin in rather than needing to be a major part of the answers,  for subsequent questions in his series.

Anyway, **poison** comes to mind.  As does a rope covered with sticky stuff that the ant can't break free of, to get tangled up in or at least get teathered with!

More *intelligent* then sticks and stones would be to use chemical pheromones. Make the ant do what you want, go where you want, including in a pen or cage.  Make it hold still while you attachnthe reins, make it refuse to perceive any alarm even as you dismember it.

Comment: Given how much larger the ants are, the humans would have a hard time making enough poisons or pheromones to affect even a single ant, and given that there can be tens or hundreds of thousands of ants in a colony, poisoning a handful is going to be pretty pointless.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that an average human is able to feel motions and surface inconsistencies of about one micron in size by touch, scale this down by a factor of 10000 (from 2 meters to 200 microns), then you are looking at a race of microscopic humanoids that can feel individual atoms(0.1nm) by touch, in a sort of Biological Atomic Force Microscopy. a Human fingertip can manipulate, in minimum, an object the size in the millimeter range, scale this down by a factor of 10000, then the smallest object your microscopic humanoids could manipulate is about 100 nanometers--the size of most biomolecules. their hair (if exists) would be about the same thickness of a chromatin fiber of most cells, and most proteins will feel like grains of sand to their touch. with a sharpened stone tool, your microscopic humanoids could easily manipulate atoms and molecules to create some of the most Formidable poisons any living being could only dream of--simply make something that will fit in to the protein molecules you want to target, and you now have a poison that will take out an entire ant with a single microscopic pinch of your humanoids' hand.

In comparison, most bacteria will be about the size of the fingertips for a Humanoid organism 200 microns in length. So bioweapons in the form of a deadly pathogen will also work for the microscopic humanoids, as most arthropods do not have an adaptive immune system, a simple breach in the joints of the ants with a deadly pathogen inserted into the Haemolymph of your target/prey is enough to take down even the largest, strongest of all ants and tarantulas.